# How to channel originate SIP in Asterisk ARI?

Tags: rest, asterisk

I try to make call via Asterisk REST API, I want to make a call like this (CLI command example):

```
channel originate SIP/4444@sipprovider application playback tt-monkeys
```

I try to use curl for that:

```
curl -v -u admin:pass -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8085/ari/channels?endpoint=SIP/1000&extension=4444&context=sipprovider"
```

When I post the request I get this error:

```
Allocation failed
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I try using SIP, I get the same error. You might have PJSIP enabled instead of SIP.

Try using PJSIP instead of SIP.
Example:

```
curl -v -u asterisk:asterisk -X POST "http://localhost:8088/ari/channels?endpoint=PJSIP/5001&extension=5002&context=internal"
```